# How to find points of intersection between ellipse and rectangle?

Tags: java, geometry

Is there a not-too-long way to calculate points of intersection for rectangle and ellipse?
I need this for my college project - vector editor with few primitives. I'm using Java, but, as I looked through oracle docs, this problem seems to be possible to solve only through geometrical approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why using Java? Solving this problem might be easier using proper tools, such as octave or maple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No complete solution, but some hints:

- A recangle consist of four line segments. If you have to points x1 and x2 of a line seqment,
  the vector equation is r=x1+t(x2-x1) while t is in (0,1).
- The equation of an ellipse with focus points f1 and f2 is |r-f1| + |r-f2| = 2a where a is the radius.
- Intersections of two figures are points r that fulfill the equations of both figures.